# Create a reference column for 2 existing models in rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, reference, migration

I am doing Rails 3.2.3 and have an issue:

I have 2 models Product and User already. The User table was created when I setup devise. I want to make product belong to user and here is what I did:

```
rails g migration AddUserToProduct user_id:integer
```

In product model, I add:

```
belongs_to :user
```

In User model, I add:

```
has_many :products
```

I ran

```
rake db:migrate
```

and i looks fine. To test that, I go to the web interface, log in and make a new product then using Rails console, I type in

```
Product.last
```

I am confused since user_id:nil which means there's no reference between the user and the product.

Is there anything wrong with my code ? What is the proper way to create a reference column between two existing Models ?

Thanks for your helps

Comment: Please show the code you're using to create new product.

Comment: Please show both of the models (user and product) and the controller code that creates instances and also your migration in db/migrate.  Ideally also a describe table in sql.  using these tools & techniques will let you also fish for yourself in the future :)

Comment: Thanks, you guys are right, I should also include the controller code. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you show your Products controller? Most likely, you have something like

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(params[:product])
  ...
end
```

if so, change it to

```
def create
  @product = current_user.products.build(params[:product])
  ...
end
```

Comment: Yes that's what my controller is. Thanks for your helps, it works.